# Typerror when creating media player with wxPython Pheonix

Tags: python, wxpython, python-3.5

Been trying to create a media player within wx.Python Phoenix (Python 3.5.2) using the wx.media module in order to play a movie trailer.
When running the following code it raises a `TypeError`:
`TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

I can't seem to find from where this error is raised.
I am new at object-oriented programming so it is possible that there are other logical mistakes in the code too.
Below is the code so far:

```
import wx,wx.media


class window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title='Media Player')
        panel1=wx.Panel(self)
        button1=wx.Button(panel1,-1,'play')
        button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,media)


class media(wx.media.MediaCtrl):
    def __init__(self):
         super(media,media).__init__(self)
         wx.media.MediaCtrl.Create(self,frame,id=-1,fileName='Trailer.wmv')
         wx.media.MediaCtrl.Load(self,'Trailer.wmv')
         wx.media.MediaCtrl.ShowPlayerControls(self)
         wx.media.MediaCtrl.Play(self)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.App()
    frame=window(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()`
```

The code should open a window in which with the press of the 'Play' button(button1) the movie trailer named 'Trailer.wmv' should be played.
Any help with the typerror or the playback of the trailer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,media)
```

where `media` is a class.  That's okay to do, although a little unconventional.  The problem is event handlers are always called with a parameter that represents the details for the event that was sent.  So wxPython is trying to call `media(event)` which, since it is a class, Python turns into `media.__init__(self, event)` and your code only accepts one parameter, so it raises an exception.

That said, a better design would be to create the media control in the Frame's `__init__` as a child of the panel, and then do just the `Load` and `Play` in the button event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `super()` call in your `media.__init__()` function to:

`super().__init__()`

Comment: Just did,unfortunately same TypeError arises

Comment: Please post the complete traceback

Comment: That's the complete TraceBack by the time you press the button:
http://imgur.com/a/AhRwW

Comment: Try to find out which line this error comes from. Normally there should be a traceback giving you the line and the function where the error occurred.

Comment: That's true, i tried to tamper with all the __init__ functions but the error was always there, that's why i reached for stack overflow